# How to change a state placeholder from the cart and checkout shipping summary

Tags: magento2, customer-address

I want to change state placeholder on the cart and checkout summary section.

In dropdown state/Province for showing "Please select state".

Instead of "Please select state" I want to display "Please select Province".

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I got the file.
Please overwrite it OR make a plugin.

Here is the path where you can make a change.

> /var/www/html/magento226/vendor/magento/module-directory/Model/ResourceModel/Region/Collection.php

line number 258

```
    if (count($options) > 0) {
            array_unshift(
                $options,
                ['title' => '', 'value' => '', 'label' => __('Please select a region, state or province.')]
            );
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Ravi.. you save my day. :)

Answer (score 0):

I see that solution is not correct,

if there is a __('Please select a region, state or province.')

that can be done in csv file only as be Magento Standards.
Like as below.
Create a folder under theme named "i18n" and add file en_US.csv and change as per your need

"Please select a region, state or province.","Change what you want to"